# How to only show one part of a web page and hide everything else using CSS on client side Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to see only these two parts highlighted here

[image]

from this particular website [tgju.org](http://tgju.org) when I open it in Firefox (v.99).

I'm using [This add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-editor-for-css-less-sass/) from Magic CSS and tried this CSS code :

```
body :not(.info-bar) :not(.date){
  display: none;
}
.info-bar {
  display: block !important;
}
.date {
  display: block !important;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working just right. As you see the smaller section (which is date and time) is shown but the price bar `(.info-bar)`  is hidden with the rest of page. How should I modify the code to only show those highlighted parts?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: `body > :not(main), main > :not(.home-quickview-wrapper), .home-quickview-wrapper > :not(.container) { display: none !important; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe it did the job, but that smaller section showing date and time (`.date`) is also hidden.  I wanted both of them to be shown.

Comment: `body > :not(main):not(:nth-child(3)), main > :not(.home-quickview-wrapper), .home-quickview-wrapper > :not(.container), #main-header > :not(.header-navbar), .header-navbar > :first-child, .nav-items > :not(.nav-time)` - the date will move to the left then, when the other elements that came before it get completely hidden via display:none. If you wanted it to keep its position, then you would need to hide those rather using `visibility: hidden` then.

Comment: Great! worked just fine. Thanks a million. If you think it would be helpful please also send the resources/tools for finding out the cascades of each item and understanding the logic behind this code, also post it as a reply so I can check it off as a working answer.  BTW I became a fan, do you have a blog or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body > :not(main):not(:nth-child(3)),
main > :not(.home-quickview-wrapper),
.home-quickview-wrapper > :not(.container),
#main-header > :not(.header-navbar),
.header-navbar > :first-child,
.nav-items > :not(.nav-time) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This should hide all the elements you don't want.

The tools I used for this, are just the browser developer tools. I started by inspecting the elements you want to keep, to see where in the DOM structure they are sitting. Then I went up from there, and checked at which level siblings could be hidden immediately, and which one would need a bit more "drilling down into" again, to keep the necessary parts.